# C++ | expression must have bool type (or be convertible to bool)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, filesystemobject

Hello i'm getting the error : expression must have bool type (or be convertible to bool)

here is my code and i cannot find a way to fix this error :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

using namespace  std;

int main() {
    for (std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator iter{ filesystem::path{"C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/userdata/"} };
       std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator{};++iter) // error appear on this line 'std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator{}'.
        
    {
        std::filesystem::remove(*iter);
    }
}
```

Obviously here my goal is to delete all files inside a folder.

But so far nothing i've tried worked..

thanks for your Help!

Comment: No screenshots or any text in images please.

Comment: You forgot to compare iterators.

Comment: You want to replace `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator{}` with  `iter != std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator{}` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Well i'm sorry but i cannot add images, i need more reps..

Comment: @LazyToxic Don't use images AT ALL unless the question is something like "Why does my code  <code> produce this graphics artefact <image>?" Pretty much every other time you use an image you're just going to tick off people who can't see the image [for any of many reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Usually a question that leans too heavily on images gets obliterated before you have time to do anything about it and long before you get an answer, so it's just not worth your time.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a Range-based For Loop such as this?

```
for(auto& p: std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(
  filesystem::path("C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/userdata/")))
{
  std::filesystem::remove(p);
}
```